# In c#, is a constructor able to make an implicit casting between different types in some scenarios?

Tags: c#, constructor

In c#, is a constructor able to make an implicit casting at run-time between different types in some scenarios?
Like from type 'System.Type' to some objects or up-casting some object to its parent or from 'int' to 'double'?

Comment: Actually the compiler does that at compile time, by adding explicit casts behind the scenes.

Comment: The constructor can invoke any member as a usual method or property could also. Wheather you can cast from one type to another is not determined by *where* you do this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide some sample code to show what you mean?

Comment: You are talking about implicit *conversions*.  Casting plays no role, that  induces an *explicit* conversion.  There is an implicit conversion from int to double, possible because all possible int values can also be stored in a double.  The compiler auto-generates the code to make the conversion.  But not the other way around, that requires (int)doubleValue.  Explicit.  Also nothing to do with a constructor.  System.Type has very few implicit conversions, only to a base class or interface.  So MemberInfo, _Type and IReflect.  And System.Object, the universal base class.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler adds explicit casting behind the scenes when possible in order to match a constructor (or any method) that doesn't directly match in the overload resolution process.

Example ([Source](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3azIyGBGDoYAXhgBGHLNk8qAJxgAzNYtQB3GADE+fMUvQTt7AL7Y3eQiXKUadG3zYLLKc3ta2YoJ8XqgwVBIybME6bIkwbi5AA===)):

```
using System;
public class C 
{
    public void M() 
    {
        int num = 1;
        var f = new Foo(num);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(double a)
    {

    }
}
```

Compiler Generated Code:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        int num = 1;
        Foo foo = new Foo((double)num);
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(double a)
    {
    }
}
```